# Iterate a loop up to the second-last element of a 2D vector

Tags: perl

As in the title, I would like to make a for iteration up to the second-last element of a 2D vector; I wrote to do:

```
for my $i (0..$#vector) {
    for my $j (1..${$vector[$i]}[-2]) {
        ....
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
${$vector[$i]}[-2]
```

gives you the **value** of the second to last element.

Instead, use:

```
for my $j (1..$#{$vector[$i]}-1) {
```

The **index** of the last element, minus one.

If you don't actually need the indices in your algorithm, consider using `for` on the array elements rather than the indices:

```
for my $outer_element (@vector) {
    for my $inner_element (@{$outer_element}[1..$#$outer_element-1]) {
        ....
    }
}
```